# ringer: help convert simple plugin to new QGIS 2.x

Tags: qgis, python, convert

I have been trying to get this simple plug-in to work on QGIS 2.x. So far i got it to load, but it does nothing! all that it is supposed to do is place a polygon where a hole (ring) is.

The code is here:

```
"""
/***************************************************************************
 Ringer
                                 A QGIS plugin
 Converts polygon inner rings to polygons
                              -------------------
        begin                : 2011-03-08
        copyright            : (C) 2011 by Pocisk
        email                : pocisk
 ***************************************************************************/

/***************************************************************************
 *                                                                         *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
 *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
 *                                                                         *
 ***************************************************************************/
"""
# Import the PyQt and QGIS libraries
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources
# Import the code for the dialog

class Ringer:

    def __init__(self, iface):
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface

    def initGui(self):
        # Create action that will start plugin configuration
        self.action = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/ringer/icon.png"), \
            "Ringer", self.iface.mainWindow())
        # connect the action to the run method
        QObject.connect(self.action, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.run)

        # Add toolbar button and menu item
        QObject.connect(self.iface, SIGNAL("currentLayerChanged(QgsMapLayer*)"), self.EnablePlugin)
        #self.iface.currentLayerChanged.QgsMapLayer.connect(self.EnablePlugin)
        #self.iface.advancedDigitizeToolBar().addAction(self.action)
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu("&Ringer", self.action)
        self.action.setEnabled(False)

    def unload(self):
        # Remove the plugin menu item and icon
        self.iface.removePluginMenu("&Ringer",self.action)
        #self.iface.advancedDigitizeToolBar().removeAction(self.action)
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)

    # run method that performs all the real work
    def run(self):
        layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        provider = layer.dataProvider()
        fet = QgsFeature()
        geom = []
        fets = []

        onlySelected = (layer.selectedFeatureCount() <> 0)
        #QInputDialog.getText( self.iface.mainWindow(), "t", "b",   QLineEdit.Normal, 'tak' )

        allAttrs = provider.attributeIndexes()
        #provider.getFetures(allAttrs) MNF
        fields = provider.fields()

        if not onlySelected:
            layer.invertSelection()

        #fets = layer.selectedFeatures() MNF
        for fet in layer.getFeatures():

        #for fet in fets:

            if fet.geometry().isMultipart():
                geom = fet.geometry().asMultiPolygon()
                for polygon in geom:
                    self.addPolys(polygon, provider, layer)
            else:
                geom = fet.geometry().asPolygon()
                self.addPolys(geom, provider, layer)

        if not onlySelected:
            layer.invertSelection()

        self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()


    def addPolys(self, polygon, provider, layer):
        rings = []
        fetOut = QgsFeature()
        if len(polygon)>1:
            rings = polygon[1:]
            for ring in rings:
                fetOut.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([ring]) )
                layer.addFeature(fetOut,True)
#            layer.setModified(True,True)

    def EnablePlugin(self):
        layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        if layer <> None:
            if (layer.isEditable()) and (layer.geometryType() == QGis.Polygon):
                self.action.setEnabled(True)
                QObject.connect(layer,SIGNAL("editingStopped()"),self.EnablePlugin)
                QObject.disconnect(layer,SIGNAL("editingStarted()"),self.EnablePlugin)
            else:
                self.action.setEnabled(False)
                QObject.connect(layer,SIGNAL("editingStarted()"),self.EnablePlugin)
                QObject.disconnect(layer,SIGNAL("editingStopped()"),self.EnablePlugin)
```

I have commented out some things and marked them with MNF. then replaced with what I thought was needed... but no longer know what to do...

Any takers?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the layer.addFeature() does not work, but if you don't care about undo/redo, you could directly use the provider to add features, by replacing layer.addFeature(fetOut,True) with provider.addFeatures([fetOut]).

This will work but will be slow on large layers. It is better to first build the list of features to add and at the end add them all at once.

Comment: Hi, I would like if there has been any news regarding putting to work this plugin??